# Any way to access magnetometer input in chrome for android?

Tags: javascript, android, magnetometer

I'm trying to start a WebGL project that works with Google Cardboard. Since the only input you can have with your phone while it's in the cardboard is a *magnetic switch* on one side that interacts with the phone's internal magnetometer, I'm curious if there's a way to access the magnetometer state data in browser.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM Event `deviceorientation` from the [DeviceOrientation Event Specification](http://w3c.github.io/deviceorientation/spec-source-orientation.html) providers you with the information needed to [calculate compass heading](http://w3c.github.io/deviceorientation/spec-source-orientation.html#worked-example).

The Android Chrome Browser is supporting that spec (according to mobilehtml5.org).

HTML 5 is agnostic to whether that information actually originates in the internal magnetometer, or some other device trick, but I guess that's fine for the scope of your question.

Comment: If this is the only solution, it doesn't work for me. The orientation of the device is already used for head tilt controls in a google cardboard headset. The only physical controlls exposed to the user come from a magnet on one end that, when moved, only effects the magnetometer. `deviceorientation` appears to use both accelerometer and magnetometer data to calculate it's values. I need a way to isolate only the magnetometer data.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'm not sure, if I understand what you mean by "isolate magnetometer data". Is the source of the compass heading really important to you, or are you unsatisfied with the precision that you get? Did you try the JavaScript-Example given in the Apendix (A.1 Calculating compass heading) to calculate the compass heading? Did it work? What is your issue with the result? I mean, just that the same Event provides you with "head tilt controls" does not spoil it for heading calculations, does it?

Comment: I think he wants to determine if the user clicked the magnetic switch on Google cardboard. I'm also trying to figure this one out.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. I'm afraid, _DeviceOrientation Event Specification_ will not help you with that, as it does not return the strength of a magnetic field, that [seems to be relevant](http://www.instructables.com/id/Dodocase-VR-Tutorial-Instructables-Build-Night/step14/How-does-the-magnetic-switch-work/). You might want to mention the magnetic switch in the question (or in a new one), so it gets proper attention :-)

Comment: I tested this, using W3C example code, with a Google Pixel 2, and it is not returning a reliable direction. It is not deriving the information from the magnetometer, which I verified by noting that it did not change when a powerful magnet was moved near the phone. Also, it's idea of North changes when you reload the web page. The direction is reported as "relative" not "absolute."  I tested Chrome, Firefox and Opera and got the same results.